# How can I create a template image to be colored at run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, uiimage, gpuimage

I have an image that is an almost flat color.  It's attached but, plain white so you can't see it easily.

[image: Sample image]
I would like to be able to dynamically color this image at runtime, but I need to do it in iOS 6 without using UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate.

The images will all start plain white with minor gradients for rounded corners.

So far my best attempt has been using GPUImage and a category on UIImage

```
@implementation UIImage (BPAdditions)

- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{

    GPUImageRGBFilter *stillImageFilter = [[GPUImageRGBFilter alloc] init];
    CGFloat red = 0.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0, alpha =0.0;
    [color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    stillImageFilter.red = red;
    stillImageFilter.green = green;
    stillImageFilter.blue = blue;
    GPUImageChromaKeyFilter *stillImageFilter2 = [[GPUImageChromaKeyFilter alloc] init];
    [stillImageFilter2 setColorToReplaceRed:0 green:0 blue:0];
    stillImageFilter2.thresholdSensitivity = 0.2;
    stillImageFilter2.smoothing = 0;
    UIImage *img = [stillImageFilter imageByFilteringImage:self];

    return [stillImageFilter2 imageByFilteringImage: img];
}
```

This would be ideal, except when I used the RGB filter it turns the clear background black. Then removing this with the chroma filter has varying quality depending on the color used.

There is a possibility that the target color will be black, in which case this solution will fail entirely.

Comment: The image is fairly simple. Would it not be easier to create this as a `UIBezierPath` in a `UIView` and render it in `drawRect`. That way you have very easy control of the colour of it. You can use PaintCode to find the code for the path.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to apply color to an existing bitmap, rather than just adding a `UIView` with the appropriate color/gradient/corner rounding on it?

Comment: Its going to use all the assets in the app this way, some are not as trivial and requires a ton of work on my part to build. My intended way means i can have our designer build the images and I can colour them for individual colour schemes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not sure if I understand what you're trying to achieve, but do you want to add a simple color tint to the base image? If so, you can achieve this with the following category on UIImage:

```
- (UIImage *)tintWithColor:(UIColor *)tintColor {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    [self drawInRect:drawRect];
    [tintColor set];
    UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(drawRect, kCGBlendModeSourceAtop);
    UIImage *tintedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return tintedImage;
}
```

**-- Update: Swift 2 version --**

```
extension UIImage {

    func tintWithColor(color:UIColor) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)
        self.drawInRect(rect)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFillUsingBlendMode(rect, CGBlendMode.SourceAtop)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }

}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, perfect!